# Populate TextView from selected ListViewItem text

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview, settext

I want to call setText on the TextView in the new activity every time I click on any text at the list view. For example, if I click on an item in the listView containing "Android" I want the word "Android" to appear in the new activity.

Find code below :

```
public class ThirdMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView lvCourses;
    String[] courses = { "Android", "HTML 5", "J2SE", "JavaScript", "MySQL", "PHP", "CSS", "JQuery", "C#"};

    String[] descr = { "Android Course", "HTML 5 Course", "J2SE Course", "JavaScript Course", "MySQL Course", "PHP Course", "CSS Course", "JQuery Course", "C# Course" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third_main);

    lvCourses = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCourses);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, courses); 

    final TextView rr = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.setT);
    lvCourses.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvCourses.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener() {     

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> lv, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position == 0){
                    rr.setText(""+descr[0]);
                    Intent e = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TeMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(e);                        
                }

                if(position == 1){
                    rr.setText(""+descr[1]);
                    Intent e = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TeMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to check all position states. just do this on **onItemClick()**

```
rr.setText(descr[position]);
Intent e = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TeMainActivity.class);
startActivity(e);
```

if you want to pass this data to new activity

```
rr.setText(descr[position]);
Intent e = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TeMainActivity.class);
e.putExtra("desc", descr[position])
startActivity(e);
```

Comment: when I emulated it give me error "Unfortunately da4  stopped"